# c# iTextHelper inject image in the middle of a new document

Tags: c#, html, pdf, itext

I have a need to write html into a pdf document and inject a generated .png in the middle of the document. I cannot find a way to do this using iTextSharp.

The total .pdf is about 4 pages without the image, the image should go on the first page, after a title.

My current code looks something like

```
 public void generatePDF(string sData, Bitmap bmp) //sData is html
 {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=summary.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        var sr = new StringReader(sData); 
        using (Document pdfDoc = new Document())
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            pdfDoc.Add(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bmp, BaseColor.BLACK));

            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(
              writer, pdfDoc, sr
            );

            Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        }

        Response.End();
 }
```

I'm writing the image to the .pdf before the text so it gets pushed to the top but ideally I'd like to replace some placeholder text with the image.

Edit:

sData is text from a .html file read from the filesystem that then has numerous search/replaces.

Comment: Why are `sw` and `hw` in your code? I don't see you using `hw` anywhere. What is `sData`? Is it XHTML? Does it have a place holder `<img>` tag for the image? It should have a placeholder and then whenever that `<img>` tag is encountered, your `ImageProvider` should return the image. Why didn't you write an `ImageProvider` implementation? Your question raises plenty of questions. You should answer those counter-questions before expecting an answer.

Comment: The sData is .html, there is no <img> tag for image.  I don't have an ImageProvider because the Image is generated from a graphics object.

Comment: If there is no image tag, you should add one. If you don't have any placeholder, how do you suppose *anyone* knows where to insert the image? Also: either I don't understand your argument for not using an ImageProvider, or you don't understand what an ImageProvider is used for. I assume the latter, because using an ImageProvider is *the only way* to insert an image that is generated from a graphics object.

Comment: I must not understand what an ImageProvider is for, I'll read through the documentation some more to understand it better. Currently, I am able to append an image to the document with

`pdfDoc.Add(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bmp, BaseColor.BLACK));`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, it's not as elegant as I'd hope.

Essentially, I split the html document into an array of strings for significant segments with placeholder segments for the images. I then check for the placeholder text when adding the array to the .pdf and replace it with an image instead.